# Polygon IO API WebSocket

Tags: python, polygon

So I am coding something that needs to get crypto price info and I am currently paying for Polygon.io's crypto live data package and need help parsing through the data I am getting. The response from the WebSocket looks like this:

```
'[{"ev":"XA","pair":"BTC-USD","v":3.85739989,"vw":23730.3964,"z":0,"o":23724.16,"c":23737.81,"h":23742.55,"l":23702,"s":1659289800000,"e":1659289860000}]'
```

I've tried several ways to get the close price ("c") like converting it to a pandas data frame but have been unsuccessful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. And I solved it. I'm editing the answer.

The response is returned in the form of a string. So the response is like this

```
'[{"ev":"XA","pair":"BTC-USD","v":3.85739989,"vw":23730.3964,"z":0,"o":23724.16,"c":23737.81,"h":23742.55,"l":23702,"s":1659289800000,"e":1659289860000}]'
```

You can use json module to solve this problem.

```
import json
response = json.loads(message)
close_price = response[0].get("c")
```

The json.loads() function will convert this string to an array of objects.